# onStop when start activity

Tags: android

I have a probleam.
When i starting an activity the onStop method is not always executed.

Sometimes i get the following after i start the activity:

onPause -> onStop -> onActivityResult -> onRestart -> onStart -> onResume

But other times i get only this:

onPause -> onActivityResult -> onResume

I used this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
pImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        "tmp_avatar_"+ String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())+ ".jpg"));
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
        pImageCaptureUri);
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
```

i tried to use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, but the results did not change.

Any other idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no guarantee how things will progress depending on underlying code in the original `Activity` or how quickly a result is returned from the `Activity` which was started for a result. What exactly is your problem? Why do you need the calling `Activity` to reach a 'stopped' state?

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are trying to avoid?.. this is a valid application lifecycle.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Depending on the situation, onStop() will not always run after onPause(). The docs specifically say this, but in low memory conditions.